# how do i return an array through a function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, split, return

```
var warriorsArray = new Array();
warriorsArray[0] = Stephen Curry;
warriorsArray[1] = Andre Iguodala;
warriorsArray[2] = Klay Thompson;
warriorsArray[3] = Andrew Bogut;
warriorsArray[4] = David Lee;

function stats(); {

}
return warriorsArray[0];
console.log warriorsArray[0];
```

Where do I put the return function?

I also wanted to split them and then assign a their number how do I do that inside the function (Curry #30)? Thank you!

Comment: How functions work is typically [explained in JavaScript tutorials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions), and you will find much more comprehensive information there than you could get in an answer. A list of things that are wrong in your code: a) No string delimiters around the array values. b) `;` following `stats()` c) `return` statement outside a function. d) missing parenthesis for `console.log` function call. Given the amount of errors in this little code, I *really* encourage you to read a tutorial again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This way.

You also have some syntax errors there

```
function stats() {
   var warriorsArray = new Array();
   warriorsArray[0] = "Stephen Curry";
   warriorsArray[1] = "Andre Iguodala";
   warriorsArray[2] = "Klay Thompson";
   warriorsArray[3] = "Andrew Bogut";
   warriorsArray[4] = "David Lee";
   return warriorsArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function stats()
{
var warriorsArray = new Array(5);
warriorsArray[0] = Stephen Curry;
warriorsArray[1] = Andre Iguodala;
warriorsArray[2] = Klay Thompson;
warriorsArray[3] = Andrew Bogut;
warriorsArray[4] = David Lee;

return warriorsArray;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to specify the length of the array and your strings are unquoted.

Answer (score 0):

```
function stats() {
    var warriorsArray = ['Stephen Curry', 'Andre Iguodala', 'Klay Thompson', 'Andrew Bogut', 'David Lee'];
    return warriorsArray;
}
```

Comment: `function stats(); {` copy&paste?

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks, you are right. I also noticed that after I posted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI, the best way to populate the array is using `.push( value )`:

```
function stats() {
   var warriorsArray = new Array();
   warriorsArray.push("Stephen Curry");
   warriorsArray.push("Andre Iguodala");
   warriorsArray.push("Klay Thompson");
   warriorsArray.push("Andrew Bogut");
   warriorsArray.push("David Lee");
   return warriorsArray;
}
console.log(stats());
```

Comment: Why push instead of indexes? Of course, you can override by mistake some existing values, is that what you were thinking?

Comment: Overriding specific values, adding and removing values, reodering values ... these are all good reasons to use `.push`